# Why is my FlatList not showing?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to load this FlatList but it is not showing anything in the screen and I am not getting errors. The breed console.log is logging an array of objects with keys of $t.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container, Content } from 'native-base';
// import BreedListItem from './BreedListItem';

class BreedList extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.breeds.breed);
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <FlatList 
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    dataSource={this.props.breeds.breed}
                    renderItem={(breed) => {
                        console.log(breed.$t);
                        return (
                        <View><Text>{breed.$t}</Text></View>
                    );
                }
                }
                    keyExtractor={(breed) => `${breed.$t}`}
                    />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        breeds: state.breeds.breeds
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BreedList);
```

The console log of this.props.breeds.breed is below.

```js
(37) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{$t: "Affenpinscher"}
1
:
{$t: "Afghan Hound"}
2
:
{$t: "Airedale Terrier"}
...
```

Comment: Can we see what `this.props.breeds.breed` looks like

Comment: I added a part of this.props.breeds.breed 
Its an array with objects

Comment: I also changed dataSource to data in the FlatList

Comment: I finally figured it out. I removed the keyExtractor and it fixed everything and used this render item 
renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.$t}</Text>}

I added in this extractor
keyExtractor={item => item.email}

Answer (score 7):

This also happens if you forget to return something from your renderItem function. For example:

```
renderItem = (row, sectID, rowID) => {
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
     <Text>{row.item}</Text>
   </View>;
};
```

As you can see the return statement is missing, but this doesn't trigger an error, warning or anything - you just get a blank Flatlist.

Answer (score 3):

The Key extractor was the main problem

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container, Content } from 'native-base';
// import BreedListItem from './BreedListItem';

class BreedList extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.breeds);
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <FlatList 
                    data={this.props.breeds}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.$t}</Text>}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.$t}
                    />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        breeds: state.breeds.breed
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BreedList);
```

Answer (score 0):

My FlatList wasn't showing too and the keyExtractor was fine

I tried to replace it with

```
<View><Text>something1</Text></View>
<View><Text>something2</Text></View>
```

And when I noticed that the second line was overriding the first, I realized there wasn't enough space for the list, so I wrapped it with **ScrollView**

```
import ScrollView from 'react-native'
```